# Can I see cross repository statistics in GitHub?

Tags: github

I often want to get a sense of the work developers on my team have done in the last week or two. Is there an application which lets me easily do things like:

- for an individual developer, across all repositories, see the pull requests they opened
- see the comments that were made on a developer's pull requests in a time frame (across all PR's, not just one by one)
- see comments that the developer made on other people's pull requests (again, across all PR's)

I can of course accomplish these manually using GitHub, by just pulling up each individual pull request, but this can be onerous.